# Replacement Window Rails Not Aligned

Tags: bathroom, windows, construction, remodeling, rough-in

I had a custom Reliabilt window built by Lowes a couple weeks ago.  I installed it and made sure everything was level and square but I noticed the rails are not in alignment.  I took the window out to see if there was a way to adjust it but I could not see any.  Is there a way to fix this?  Is it a problem with the installation or possibly a manufacturer defect?  This was my first install so it's possible I messed something up during install.  Any guidance would be appreciated

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you measured the stops to verify they are the same width? You can check the window by measuring corner to corner diagonally they should be the same. If they are and the height and width are the same it might be the guides are slightly different or not fully seated.

Comment: I checked the stops and they are the same size on both sides.  I am baffled by this...

Comment: Turns out I wasn't quite square. Once I fixed the squaring the rails aligned as expected